# MySQLAdmin replace text in a field with percent in text

Tags: mysql, replace, mysqladmin

Using MySQLAdmin. Moved data from Windows server and trying to replace case in urls but not finding the matches. Need slashes as I don't want to replace text in anything but the urls (in post table). I think the %20 are the problem somwhow?

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = replace(field, '/user%20name/', '/User%20Name/')
```

The actual string is more like:

```
https://www.example.com/forum/uploads/user%20name/GFCI%20Stds%20Rev%202006%20.pdf
```

Comment: What is the current output from that replacement, and what result do you actually want?  Then there is the question of what encoded URLs are doing in your database.

Comment: `%` is a wildcard character in MySQL, so I suspect you may need to excape it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think `%` only has a wildcard meaning when used in `LIKE`.  In a simple replacement, it should behave like any other character.

Comment: Doesn't find any matches... code does nothing.

Comment: I made a big mistake without noticing and I can't seem to edit my original question or tags. The problem is in phpMyAdmin and NOT MySQLAdmin. Very sorry for confusion I caused by that slip up. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In a case you are using MariaDB you have REGEXP_REPLACE() function.

But best approach is to dump the table into the file. Open it in a Notepad ++

and run regex replace like specified on a pic:
Pattern is: `(https:[\/\w\s\.]+uploads/)(\w+)\%20(\w+)((\/.*)+)`
Replace with: `$1\u$2\%20\u$3$4`

[image]

Then import the table again
Hope this help

Comment: 160,000+ records would rather not unless last resort.

Comment: I opened 1,5 million rows table, but if you on Linux with the same pattern you can create Perl or bash script

Answer (score 0):

If its MariaDB, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '\/user%20name\/', '\/User%20Name\/');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please check, what is actually stored in the database: `%20` is a html-entity which represents a whitespace. Usually, when you are storing this inside the database, it will be represented as an actual whitespace (converted before you store it) -> Hence your replace doesn't match the actual data.

The second option that might be possible - depending on what you want to do: You are seeing the URL containing `%20`, therefore you created your database records (which you would like to fetch) with that additional `%20` - And when you now try to query your results based on the actual url, the `%20` is replaced with an "actual" whitespace (before your query) and hence it doesn't match your stored data.

Comment: I look at my local copy that I published using MySqlWorkbench and pasted text into notepad++ and %20 is there.

Comment: There are quotes around the strings? src="https://www.example.com/forum/uploads/User%20Name/tn/tn_20174212624_IMG_0393.jpg"